# Menu hover is not behaving correct, submenu hover disappears

Tags: css, menu, hover, submenu

The problem with this menu (http://thepiratehenk.nl/pgwe/) is that, when I hover the submenu to the right, it disappears.

(It also doesn’t work in Internet Explorer; that’s the next issue to fix.)

Comment: increase the `z-index` for the sub-menu

Comment: Can you give me an value?

Comment: A most-likely unrelated issue: You have a `.naarlinks` `div` nested directly inside a `ul` tag. The only element that can be directly inside a `ul` tag is an `li` tag. This may or may not cause a problem on some browsers.

Comment: The simple reason for that is that i am a complete css newbie, especially with  this kind of menu.. I do not know how to build this up correctly..

Comment: Is there someone who saved the whole css file of my site? I accidentally saved it with a blank document.. No way for me to retreive it back.

Comment: Well, next time, be sure to use version control, and keep separate copies as backups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following CSS rule:

```
.navi nav > ul > li:hover {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

This ensures that the current menu item and its submenu will always appear above the other menu items.

**Two main issues**

1. Menu items overlapping other menu items
2. Menu items overlapping the submenu of the previous menu items

**Issue #1**

Issue #1 is caused by having the `:hover` on the `li`, but performing the rotation on the `a` tag inside it (not having the `:hover` and rotation on the same element). This could be addressed in one of two ways:

1a. Temporarily give the current menu item (that the mouse is over) a larger z-index value than any other menu item. This may be doable with CSS alone using `li:hover`.

1b. Rotating the menu `li` rather than the `a` tag, and then unrotating the submenu `ul` tag inside it (so that `:hover` and rotation are on the same element).

**Issue #2**

The bottom corner of each menu item is sitting above the submenu of the previous menu items. The submenus should always be above all of the menu items.

The 1a solution mentioned above may fix issue #2 as well (setting the z-index of the menu `li` to a larger `z-index` on `:hover`.

**Minor issue**

Another issue, mentioned in the comments above and by @blackhawk, is having the `.naarlinks` `div` nested directly inside the `ul` tag. It now appears that this was in fact unrelated to the problem above, but it's still not safe to leave it like that. Aside from the risk of it causing odd behavior in some browsers, it will also prevent the HTML from validating.

The `.naarlinks` `div` appears to only have `padding-left: 100px;`. I'm not sure if that style was even taking effect, since the `div` is improperly nested, but if you do need that style, you could try adding it to the submenu `ul` in some way.

First, I'd recommend simply deleting the `.naarlinks` `div`s and see how that affects the page. Then see if you need to add any styling to the submenu `ul` tags to correct it.

After deleting the `div`s, try changing the padding in the submenu `ul` to the following:

```
.navi nav li ul {
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 110px;
}
```

Comment: @jediah: Added some code to the answer. It looks like a simple CSS fix may be possible.

Comment: Hero! That z-index: 2; did the actual trick! But i understand that this is not the "cleanest" way to do this?

Comment: @jediah: I think it's the appropriate solution, and the cleanest one possible (it took a while to realize that). It would still be a good idea to address the matter of having a `div` inside a `ul` tag, but that certainly did not appear to be the cause of this problem. You could try first simply deleting each of those divs and see how the page is affected. You may need to move the `.naarlinks` class and the related CSS styles to the `ul` for each submenu.

Comment: @jediah: I added a little more info to the answer, about the nested `div`. @blackhawk: thanks! :)

Comment: Very usefull Matt! Thousand thanks! I will try to remove/re-do the div tormorrow since its bedtime now.

Comment: @MattCoughlin Removed the div-css anyway, the only thing affected is the text.

Comment: @jediah: I added some code at the end of the answer that may restore the intended padding you lost by removing the div.

Comment: @MattCoughlin Will fix the text later, since that is not a big issue. Do you have any suggestions to make this work in IE?

Comment: @jediah: Rotation doesn't work in IE8 and earlier, and some browsers require a prefix (`-ms-transform` for IE9, `-webkit-transform` for Chrome and Safari). What versions of IE are you having trouble with (after making the above fix)?

Comment: Matt, i want to thank you again. I finished the menu today with all possible transforms. As far as i can see it works on all common browsers now. (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE(MS supported versions) and Opera.) Does this css comply to the requirements nowadays? According to you?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a div element as the first child inside of an un-ordered list. That is why your page is broken.

A basic structure of an unordered list usually looks like this...

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

not like this...

```
<ul>
<div>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</div>
</ul>
```

But to answer your question - you are missing one tinnnnny little thing in your css...

.navi nav li ul:hover {
  display:block
}

Comment: How can i replace that div with the same effect?